# Configuration of exponential function

Tags: probability, functions

Given a function $f(x) = k^{bx}$

Is there something you can add to that function in order of making it decrease faster in the beginning and still "*last*" longer?

It seems like varying both $k$ and $b$ changes both the *longlastivity* and the initial derivative in the same direction.

With *longlastivity* I mean how long it takes before the function is practically zero.

Comment: Last longer than what?

Comment: Presumably $0 \lt k^b \lt 1$. You could let $c=k^b$ and your function would be $f(x)=c^x$

Comment: @GFauxPas than what it currently does. Meaning that it should take longer before it gets to 0.

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly, so here are some wild suggestions: The density of a Pareto distribution. At $x=0$, it starts out by decreasing fast, and then it eases up: https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Pareto_distribution Or maybe a logistic function, but instead of doing what it does in an increasing manner, you flip it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function